# How to terminate a thread that is hanging on blocking IO in a platform independent manner?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

Since non-blocking console IO is not supported in std C++, I am trying to do the console input on a separate thread. I still have the problem of terminating the thread from outside however.
How can I do it without Unix signals?

If I use select() it can signal if something is in the input buffer, but if it is not a whole line (containing a newline), then "cin << myvar" will still block and I cannot test my stop-flag in between.

Any C++11 conformant solution interests me.

Comment: Terminating threads is arguably *less* supported than non-blocking console input.  At least you can find a library for console i/o.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't in general.  Under Posix, you can set the thread up to catch a
specific signal, and use `pthread_kill()`; after returning from the
signal handler, blocking IO at the system level (i.e. `read()`) will
return with `errno` equal `EINTR`.  Beyond that, you're pretty much at
the mercy of the iostream implementation, which has two choices (the
implementor of iostream, not you):

- it can loop back and retry tge read, or
- it can treat it as an error condition, and set `failbit`.

In the first case, there's not much you can do about it, short of
implementing your own `streambuf` and using it (which, for console
input, isn't as difficult as it seems).  For the second, you should set
`errno` to 0 before reading, and check it after a read failure (at the
iostream level); if it is `EINTR`, you can then take appropriate action,
not forgetting to reset the error (`std::ios_base::clear()`) if you
intend to reuse the stream.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cin.get()`, to read a single character, and `select` in combination to avoid blocking the thread. Also `cin.rdbuf()->in_avail()` returns the numbers of ready chars in the buffer.

Comment: cin.get() blocks until a newline has been read (buffered IO). in_avail() has the same issue: it cannot tell if there is a newline in the buffer or not (so that get() will block or not).

Comment: This answer is wrong.  `cin.get()` will call `read` at some point, and `read` will block; you can't use `select` if the thread is blocked in `read`.  You could implement a `streambuf` which used `select` on the fd 0 (for standard in) and on a pipe; pushing a character into the pipe would deblock the `streambuf`, which could then do whatever is appropriate.  (This is an alternative strategy to `pthread_kill` if `istream` doesn't propagate an `EINTR`.)

Comment: And `in_avail()` is not required to check if more characters are available; it only returns the status of the local buffer.  Which means that even after the user hits return, it will continue to return 0.

Comment: checking cin.rdbuf()->in_avail() followed by calling std::getline if cin.rdbuf()->in_avail() succeeds does *not* work, likely because the buffer has no data in it, and never will, since cin.get isn't called.

Answer (score 0):

In my humble experience, never seen a stable way to cancel a synchronous and/or blocking I/O operation. That is, it can't be done with "cin >>" operator.

Comment: OK. Is it any other platform independent way to do it besides "cin >>"?